# Grep out all file extensions from input

Tags: bash, unix, grep, file-extension

My input is a large list of files. They could have any characters in the name (including periods, because there are some package names as well). Here's some small sample input:

```
com.test.impl.servlets.Test.xml
TestClass.class
TestClass1.class
Test2.java
Test3.java
```

I want to know all of the different file extensions in my list, so essentially, I want egrep -o everything after the *last* period. Something like this:

```
input | xargs <unknown command but probably egrep> | sort -u
```

Would return:

```
.xml
.class
.java
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `grep -o '\.[^.]*$'`:

```
$ echo 'com.test.impl.servlets.Test.xml
TestClass.class
TestClass1.class
Test2.java
Test3.java' | grep -o '\.[^.]*$' | sort -u
.class
.java
.xml
```

or `sed 's/.*\././'`:

```
$ echo 'com.test.impl.servlets.Test.xml
TestClass.class
TestClass1.class
Test2.java
Test3.java' | sed 's/.*\././' | sort -u
.class
.java
.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If your make has pcre compiled in

```
$ grep -P -o '.*\.\K.*'
```